# Need clarification on Android Market version requirement in support In-app Billing

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-billing

I am confused by one statement in Google’s official document:

“If your device is running Android 3.0, in-app billing requires version 5.0.12 (or higher) of the MyApps application. 
If your device is running any other version of Android, in-app billing requires version 2.3.4 (or higher) of the Android Market application.“

I am wondering if it means:

1. Devices running Android 3.0 (Exclude 3.1 and 3.2, only 3.0 whose SDK version is 11) requires MyApps application version >= 5.0.12
2. Devices running other versions of Android (Include 1.x, 2.x, 3.1, 3.2 and 4.x) requires Android Market application version >= 2.3.4

Or does it mean the following:

1. Devices running Android 3.0 (Include 3.0, 3.1 and 3.2, whose SDK versions are 11, 12 and 13) requires MyApps application version >= 5.0.12
2. Devices running other versions of Android (Include 1.x, 2.x and 4.x) requires Android Market application version >= 2.3.4

Could someone please help clarify our confusion?

Thanks,
Tim

Answer (score 2):

I haven't started venturing into the 3.x and up yet (currently interested in phones only, not tablets) but I can tell you that Google’s official documents are in way too many cases not up-to-date. At least in the case of In-app Billing, "Android Market application >= 2.3.4":

My device is running Android version 2.3.4 and Market version 2.3.6 and the sample application kept greeting me with an error message, saying that I "cannot use the Android Market at this time". The error disappeared only after I updated it to the latest 3.4.4.

Does this mean that In-app Billing always requires the **latest** Android Market application version? I still don't have an answer to [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8760775/in-app-billing-requires-the-latest-market-version-not-v2-3-4-as-documented).

**Update:** If you look at Google's help page for [In-app Purchasing Availability](http://support.google.com/androidmarket/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1050566&dl=us), it reads:

> In order to make in-app purchases, you'll need an active Internet
>   connection and the **latest version** of Android Market installed on
>   your phone. In addition, Android 3.0 users must have MyApps 5.0.12 or
>   higher. Please visit our Updating Android Market article for more
>   information.

Which confirms my conclusion:

- For Android version < 3.0, you must use the **latest version** of
  Android Market, regardless of its number (currently 3.4.4)
- For Android version >= 3.0, you must use the **latest version** of
  Android Market, as long as it is **MyApps 5.0.12** or higher.

Does this help?