# In-app Billing requires the LATEST Market version, not v2.3.4 as documented

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-billing

I have Market version 2.3.6 and I was trying to test the sample application per the [instructions](http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/billing_testing.html#billing-testing-static) which state that:

> If your device is running Android 3.0, in-app billing requires version
>   5.0.12 (or higher) of the MyApps application. If your device is running any other version of Android, in-app billing requires version
>   **2.3.4** (or higher) of the Android Market application.

Well, my device is running Android version 2.3.4 and Market version 2.3.6 and the sample application kept greeting me with an error message, saying that I "cannot use the Android Market at this time".

So, I manually started the Android Market, then went to check the version (in the Settings > Manage Applications) and I was reading the information, it automatically changed from 2.3.6 to the latest 3.4.4.

Now the sample application runs without this error.

So my question is why did I get this error message?

- Is it due to a "bug" in the documentation and really In-app Billing
  requires the LATEST Market version and not not v2.3.4 as documented?
- Or is it because my attempt to run the sample application caught the
  Market application in transition, i.e. during an automatic update?